# Recieving error: "Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference" in slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm probably gonna get ripped a new one for asking this question, but I'm at my wits end and the endless array of similar questions are not helping me.

I've been trying to make a slideshow that slides right. The thought processes are shown below and the line where I'm getting the error is marked by two question mark.

```
var slideIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("Slides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
//I thought that maybe the error originated here so I triple checked everything here

showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        if (slides[i].style.transform == "translateX(100%)") {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
            //make sure slide that's about to be replaced doesn't interfere with next one.
            }
        slides[i].style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
        //return all slides to -100% position. (Is already an issue because current
        //slide is supposed to move to the right but it'll jump. I'll figure this out,
        //this is NOT my question)
    }
    //??Error here. I know the line is empty I don't understand it neither??
    //Maybe it's the previous 'for' loop?

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
    //Move old slide 100%.
    slideIndex++;
    //Next Slide
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1; }
    else if (slideIndex < 0) { slideIndex = slides.length; }
    //Self-explanatory
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "inline-block";
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.transform = "translateX(0)";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    //Move new slide in and activate concurrent dot
    if (slideIndex == 1) {
        setTimeout(showSlides(), 10000);
    }
    // I want the first picture to last longer
    else {
        setTimeout(showSlides(), 5000)
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="Slides">
    <img src="~/Images/Slideshow/Gallery-1.jpg" class="Slides-Images">
</div>

<div class="Slides">
    <img src="~/Images/Slideshow/Gallery-2.jpg" class="Slides-Images">
</div>

<div class="Slides">
    <img src="~/Images/Slideshow/Gallery-3.jpg" class="Slides-Images">
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.Slides {
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform 2s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I tried to create a Jsfiddle but my internet isn't fast enough for it D:

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your statement

```
var slideIndex = 0;
```

the following statement in function

```
slides[slideIndex - 1].style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
```

will try to evaluate `slides[-1]` hence the error.

Comment: That makes sense, but if i amend that won't the array hit `slide[3]` and return anoher error?

Comment: @James9oo0 - It will but it will never be 3 in your for loop because of `i < slides.length`. The maximum value of i will be 2 under your test case. And if it does, you need to put extra check where `slideIndex` should fall in the range.

Comment: Lmao in the pursuit to avoid an error I created a more glaring one. Thanks a lot! I'll mark yours as the answer once I'm able.

Comment: I don't know if it's appropriate but I'm going to steal your attention again. I'm receiving the same error now on line `slides[slideIndex].style.display = "inline-block";` I've removed all the -1 on the slideIndex things. Any ideas what may have caused this error? Is there some way I can track the variables like you can do on C# console app?

Comment: i don't see the declaration of `slideIndex` anywhere on the code, it's a global variable or something?

Comment: @LPZadkiel yes it is, I need to use it for other functions of the slideshow. It's the first line of code I've written in the question

Comment: @James9oo0 - When `i` was 2 then `slideIndex` became 3 after `slideIndex++`. You need to reset it again as for the next time it will be 3 the cause of error. Hence, some check where you reset when you reach the extremes.

Comment: i don't see it on the code but have you make sure if `slideIndex` is not `undefined`? because if it is, `slides[undefined]` will return undefined

Comment: @LPZadkiel - slideIndex is the first line of the code snippet shared.

Comment: shouldn't my `if` and `else if` checks fix that? The ones after `slideIndex++`

Comment: now, if you change the `slideIndex - 1` for `slideIndex`. This line of code has to change aswell -> `if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1; }` for `if (slideIndex >= slides.length) { slideIndex = 1; }`. BTW should be 0 not 1 and if you would have changed the initial slideIndex for 1 that should have fixed the problem on the original code

Comment: It should be 0 then. There is a problem with the statements. You can simply solve by logging the values in console or break points. That will give you a better idea about the real cause of error.

Comment: @James9oo0 - Good to hear that :)